# (Closed) Discord bot leave message with author and thumbnail of user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot create embed leave messages which is mostly figured out but I'm struggling with author and thumbnail because I want them to have the person who left pfp. I also want to how to set the author user as the person who left but specifically in the format of bot#0001.

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#78a6dd')
    .setDescription(`<@${member.user.id}> left`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code

```
    client.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
    let goodbyembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor(${member.user.tag} + " just left!", member.user.avatarURL())
.setDescription( /* Message here */)
.setColor('#78a6dd');
member.guild.channels.cache.get("samechannelid").send(goodbyembed) 

        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: It gives me an error when i try to run my bot

Comment: @NonLogicalCookie what error?

Comment: ".setAuthor(${member.user.tag} + " just left!", member.user.avatarURL())
           ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: @NonLogicalCookie Do you open a function before this code?, From what I analyzed there should be no arguments missing in the code I quoted

Comment: Hey ya I think so but I ended up figure it and it ended up looking like 
 .setAuthor(" " + member.user.tag + " ", member.user.avatarURL())
p.s tysm

Comment: change to `.setAuthor(`${member.user.tag} just left`, member.user.avatarURL())`